# Typescript Conditionally extending an "Array or Object" not working as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a simple typescript type generic that looks like this:

```js
type APIDataShape<T extends { id: unknown } | Array<{ id: unknown }>> =
  T extends Array<any>
    ? Array<{
        id: T[number]["id"];
        attributes: Omit<T, "id">;
      }>
    : {
        id: T["id"];
        attributes: Omit<T, "id">;
      };
```

It's very simple, I'm expecting either an object or an array of objects that has an 'id' property, & I want to map that to a slightly different shape.

But when I'm writing the code above, I'm getting an error on the `id: T["id"];` part saying:

`Type '"id"' cannot be used to index type 'T'`

This is honestly very weird cause it's very clear that if T isn't an Array, then it's an object with {id: unknown}, so why is TypeScript saying that it can't be indexed???

I've spent quite some time playing around with it, but couldn't figure the reason, so if someone knows why this is happening, please tell me.

(NOTE: I know that using 2 `extend` clauses would fix the issue, but I'm more interested in the "Why" of it. Cause it feels to me that even with one `extend` it should have worked, so I want to understand why it didn't)

Thanks.

Comment: Ts is stupid, you need two extend clauses

Answer (score 0):

you need to narrow down the type

```
type APIDataShape<T extends { id: unknown } | Array<{ id: unknown }>> =
  T extends Array<{ id: unknown }>
  ? Array<{
    id: T[number]["id"];
    attributes: Omit<T, "id">;
  }>
  : T extends { id: unknown } ? {
    id: T["id"];
    attributes: Omit<T, "id">;
  } : never;
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Indexed Access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) you need to narrow the type to one concrete type or at least [discriminate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) the union. One approach using [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).

```
type APIDataShape<T extends {id: unknown} | Array<{id: unknown}>> =
  T extends (infer U)[]
    ? {
        id: U extends {id: infer I} ? I : unknown;
        attributes: Omit<U, "id">;
      }[]
    : T extends {id: infer I}
    ? {
        id: I;
        attributes: Omit<T, "id">;
      }
    : never;
```

You might wonder why TypeScript does not realize that `T` in the *else path* (`:`) of the conditional must be of the type you did not check for in your condition as there are only two types in the initial Union. The unsatisfying answer is that TypeScript is very limited in its [Control-Flow Analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) with [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and especially with [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

Comment: yeah, using 2 `extends` clauses works, & that's what I'm doing now.
However, I wanted to know why this is happening in the first place...

Cause I have a union with 2 types that are clearly different.
& since the extend clause check if it's an array or not, then theoretically, in the "else" part, 'T' should be the other element of the union which is the object...